# No open activity paypal

Tags: android, paypal

Not work paypal activity, no open view, when press on botton no open paypal 
 Please help me, sorry my english,
The methods below shows the configuration and the intention where I call a paypal service

```
View.OnClickListener pagarPaypal = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Inicializar Paypal
            onBuyPressed("0.00", "USD");
        }
    };
```

Metodos de configuracion

```
 public PayPalConfiguration initConfigPaypal() {

        PayPalConfiguration payPalConfiguration = new PayPalConfiguration();
        payPalConfiguration.acceptCreditCards(true);
        payPalConfiguration.environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX);
        payPalConfiguration.merchantName("MERCHANT_NAME");
        payPalConfiguration.clientId("CLIENT_ID");
        payPalConfiguration.merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"));
        payPalConfiguration.merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"));
        payPalConfiguration.languageOrLocale("es_MX");

        return payPalConfiguration;
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(String cantidad, String typeMoney) {
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new
                PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(cantidad),
                typeMoney,
                "Sample Item",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, initConfigPaypal());
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
        getActivity().startService(intent);

    }
```

Comment: please see my answer. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

In your `intent` you are using `PayPalService.class` instead of `PaymentActivity.class`. `PayPalService.class` does not have any `View`.

**Try this:**

```
// Import
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;

............
.................

public void onBuyPressed(String cantidad, String typeMoney) {
    PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new
            PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(cantidad),
            typeMoney,
            "Sample Item",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, initConfigPaypal());
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

Here is a very nice article [Android Integrating PayPal using PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-1/)

Here is the [PayPal SDK class description](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);`
With this I solved the problem, I forgot to mention that I am in a fragment, there is no function at all because when I perform onclick only the paypal view flashes, but it does not load completely

Comment: Ohh my mistake... updated my answer. Is it working now?

Comment: No, just on the paypal screen and close again, what should I put in the ActityOnResult part? Possibly this is my mistake

Comment: Lol Ok, look at the log and it is why not accept the amount "0.00",

Comment: If my answer seems useful, then please mark as right answer and vote it up. Thanks inn advance :)